# c# datatable summary same row value in new row

Tags: c#, datatable, summary

How to in c# using datatable sum same cell value and show it in new row.
Like in picture link below: for same price value sum size value and show in new row over specyfic price.

[Click to open picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHsMA.png)

Thanks for help!

Marc Jone

Answer (score 0):

**Create a DataRow:**

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();//For example use your data table
//Creating a data row for calculating
DataRow Fndr = dt.NewRow();
//Here i added on 0th cell you can add anywhere based on data
Fndr[0] = "Total";
```

**Calculation:**

```
decimal d = 0;
for (int l = 1; l < dt.Columns.Count; l++)
{
    string s = dt.Columns[l].ColumnName.ToString();
    decimal total = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => !r.IsNull(dt.Columns[l].ColumnName.ToString()) 
                  && decimal.TryParse(r[dt.Columns[l].ColumnName.ToString()].ToString(), out d))
        .Sum(r => d);
    Fndr[l] = total;
}
```